# Find closest value in BST - why does my recursive code always return null?

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree (as you can see in the image below). I am supposed to find the closest value of the target value contained in the BST.

This is the sample code I wrote, in this particular case I am supposed to return "13" but always end up returning "null". I find this very strange as I have a condition

Below is the code I wrote, from printing output I see that it goes through the correct steps in the tree, but then always returns null instead of what I think should be the closest value.

```
def findClosestValueInBst(tree, target):
    return saveClosest(tree, target, 1000)

def saveClosest(tree, target, closest):
    if(tree is None):
        return closest
    if(abs(tree.value - target) < abs(closest - target)):
        closest = tree.value
    if(abs(tree.value < target)):
        saveClosest(tree.right, target, closest)
    elif(tree.value > target):
        saveClosest(tree.left, target, closest)
```

[image]

Comment: You generally need to return the results of the recursive function call.

Comment: omg... I am an idiot, thank you so much Mark!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're not returning anything in the second if statement